# Is there a gas fee when storing the mapping type of key?

Tags: solidity, gas, mapping

I have a question about mapping.

```
mapping(uint => address) public id;

function setMapping() public {
    id[1] = msg.sender;
}
```

As in the code above, if you put a key and a value in the mapping and save the data, does the data i put in the key incur a gas fee?

Where is the mapping key stored in the smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings are kept in storage. Cost of storing in a mapping is approximately the cost of an SSTORE operation, which varies depending on if you're writing an entirely new value or if you're overwriting an old value. Check out [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/#55?fork=arrowGlacier) for more information about the cost of an SSTORE operation.

Every smart contract on Ethereum has its own key/value storage where keys and values are both 32 bytes. Solidity mapping values are placed into this key/value storage according to the logic defined [in the Solidity documentation regarding state variable layout in storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage). For mappings, this is:

```py
storage_key = keccak256(concat(uint256(mapping_key), uint256(mapping_variable_position)))
```

Where `mapping_key` is the key in the mapping that you're updating and `mapping_variable_position` is the position of the mapping within your contract. `mapping_variable_position` literally is just the order in which your mapping was defined -- if the mapping is the very first variable in the contract then `mapping_variable_position` will be 0. Second variable will be 1, etc etc.

For your example, assuming the `id` mapping is the first variable defined in the contract, `id[1]` is found at:

```py
mapping_key = 1
mapping_variable_position = 0

storage_key = keccak256(concat(uint256(mapping_key), uint256(mapping_variable_position)))
            = keccak256(
                concat(
                  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001,
                  0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                )
              )
            = 0xada5013122d395ba3c54772283fb069b10426056ef8ca54750cb9bb552a59e7d
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it costs gas. Mappings are stored on the `storage` level. When you initialize a `mapping`, the `key` and `value` are set to default (in this case `0` & `0x0`). So when you call `setMapping` you are changing that data and updating/changing data on blockchain costs

Answer (score 1):

When you create the`mapping` the main thing that happens is the compiler reserves a storage slot which is used to organize storage. The effect is entirely in the bytecode for the contract.

`public` makes it create a function to return key values.

Unset values are initially binary zero because nothing has been written and all keys "exist".

Setting a value causes an SSTORE. The cost varies. Writing to a previously zero key is more expensive than overwriting a non-zero value.

Hope it helps.